# Vaadin GWT error

Tags: vaadin

I see this when I start my server:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.vaadin.client.ui.AbstractComponentConnector

Have the libraries in-place and in my `gwt.xml` I have:

```
<inherits name="com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet" />
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Did you include `vaadin-client` library in your build path?

If you use `maven`, it should be something like this in your dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.7</version> <!-- 7.0.7 or any version that you use -->
    </dependency>
```